# display the last id from a colomn - ZendFramwork

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework

I want to display the last ID from a column called `id_client`, I'm using ZendFramework.

This is how i write my query in php:

```
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select('ID_CLIENT');
$select->order('ID_CLIENT DESC');
$result = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select);
$result = $result[0];
var_dump($result);
```

The problem is that it returns a select * and I do not understand why knowing that I specify that I had to select only id_client :

[image]

Anyone as an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is ZF 1.x. Column selection is done in "from" method. Your query should be something like this:

```
// $db should be a Zend_Db instance
$select = $db->select()
              ->from(
                  array('alias' => 'table_name'),
                  array('ID_CLIENT')
              );
$select->order('ID_CLIENT DESC');
$result = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select);
$result = $result[0];
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good ol' Zend Framework 1.

If I understand it right, you are trying to retrieve **only** the id_client of the **last** row of that table.

If so, you have to sort the results by id_client in descending order and then retrieve the first line with the method `current()`. Don't forget that the result is an object (`Zend_Db_Table_Row`) and it has to be accessed properly.

```php
$select = $this->getDbTable();
$select->from('TABLE_NAME'); // Not really necessary
$select->columns('ID_CLIENT');
$select->order('ID_CLIENT DESC');
$result = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select)->current();
$lastIdClient = $result->id_client;
```